# JBoss Wildfly 9.0 ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException [asm 3.1]

Tags: java, exception, jboss, wildfly-9

While deploying war in JBoss getting below exception: Using asm3.1 jar

I've verified this on google. But I didn't get much info. It said that check asm jar dependency with java8 version and I've tried updating asm latest builds also after updating latest builds (asm 5.0.3 or later) I got another error as incompatibleclasschangeerror

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9578
        at   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9578
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
```

Comment: Please expand the question. Did you Google the errors? What did you try to do? Does this war file work in other environments? How do you know that it works?

Comment: Yes, I've verified this on google. But I didn't get much info. It said that check asm jar dependency with java8 version and I've tried updating asm latest builds also after updating latest builds (asm 5.0.3 or later) I got another error as incompatibleclasschangeerror.

Comment: Excellent! Now please add that to the question. That way people trying to help you will have more information to work with.

Comment: Sure, Thanks @Uberhumus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the lambda dependency from my application and verified it. It is working fine. (asm 3.1, JBoss wildfly 9.0, Java 1.8).

Comment: Can you clarify which dependency you have removed please?